# Difference between various shear forces

Tags: stress-strain

What is the difference between $\tau_{xy}$ and $\tau_{zy}$; because as far as i know the first character of subscript represents the direction to which the stress is perpendicular and other the actual direction.

So a vector perpendicular to $x$ along $y$ and another perpendicular to $z$ along $y$, shouldn't they be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\tau_{xy}$ and $\tau_{zy}$ act in the same direction but they *act on different faces*.

This diagram should clear it up for you:

[image]